# Android; App installs and runs OK, but when I exit I can't find its launcher icon in menu

Tags: android, android-2.1-eclair, android-install-apk

I've created a simple application and put it onto my device.

I use a file browser to locate the APK, it installs successful and I can run it OK (when clicking "run" after install completes)

However, if I then exit the application, I'm unable to see a launcher for it on my apps menu (where I would expect it, like other apps I've created)

At the moment, every time I want to run the app, I first have to re-install it so I can access it, surely there must be a better way?

Manifest attached

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.jameselsey"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      >
    <application android:icon="@drawable/globe" android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:name=".GeoCodeTest"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted this from CommonsWare, from http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fc4816cac75c7edc/c867733d8380dea9?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=Missing+application+icon+in+All+Application+drawer#c867733d8380dea9:

*"If you on Android 1.5, and you already have that intent filter, and you 
still do not see your icon, and you may already have an application 
installed that shares the same Java package (e.g., 
package="com.commonsware.android.foo" in your  element), try 
removing the earlier application and re-installing the new one. You 
cannot have two applications installed with the same package. In Android 
1.1 and earlier, the new one would overwrite the old one -- not anymore."*